# Implement a function with a "mapping" closure

Tags: rust, closures

I have a vector `my_vec: Vec<MyStruct>` and I want to write a function that can be called like this:

```
let strings = my_func(&my_vec, |o| o.some_string);
let numbers = my_func(&my_vec, |o| o.foo + 5);
```

So basically I need to pass a ref to the vector and a closure `f` and I need the function to call `.map(f)` on the vector plus some other stuff and return a new vector of values having the same type as the one returned in the closure.

Comment: and the function should return what?

Comment: Netwave, I've explained that in the question: "and return a new vector of values having the same type as the one returned in the closure". So, it should be a generic. For example, if the passed closure returns `i64`, `my_func` should return `Vec<i64>`.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the [documentation of `Iterator::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) and use the same trait bounds for you closure parameter, i.e. `fn my_func<B, F>(v: Vec<MyStruct>, f: F) -> Vec<B> where F: FnMut(MyStruct) -> B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want do something like this?

```
struct MyStruct {
    o: i32
}

fn my_func<T, F>(_v: &Vec<MyStruct>, f: F) -> T
    where F: FnOnce() -> T
{
    f()
}

fn main() {
    let i = vec!(MyStruct{o:3}, MyStruct{o:4} );
    let strings = my_func(&i, || "a string");
    let numbers = my_func(&i, || 5);
    
    println!("{} {}", strings, numbers);
}
```

According to your comment, you can do this

```
struct MyStruct {
    o: i32,
}

fn my_func<T, F>(v: &[MyStruct], f: F) -> Vec<T>
where
    F: FnMut(&MyStruct) -> T,
{
    v.iter().map(f).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let i = vec![MyStruct { o: 3 }, MyStruct { o: 4 }];

    let strings = my_func(&i, |o| o.o + 5);
    let numbers = my_func(&i, |o| format!("{} string", o.o));

    println!("{:?} {:?}", strings, numbers);
}
```

Comment: Not quite. See my comment above. `my_func` needs to return `Vec<T>` and its implementation should be something like `_v.iter().map(f).collect()` (that doesn't compile, but you get the point).

Comment: @at54321, my update help you more?

Comment: Yes, Zeppi. Now it does what I need. Thanks! +1